# Why are the Cat and Anodos, in MacDonald’s Phantastes, both tortured with electric shocks?

Tags: george-macdonald, phantastes

Near the end of Chapter 3 of *Phantastes* the flower fairies get hold of a cat and proceed to forcefully and violently “remove” electrical sparks from the the feline:

> ...by this time the party which had gone towards the house, rushed out again, shouting and screaming with laughter. Half of them were on the cat’s back, and half held on by her fur and tail or ran beside her; till, more coming to their help, the furious cat was held fast and they proceeded to pick the sparks out of her with thorns and pins, which they handled like harpoons. (P. 41, of the Johannsen edition)

In Chapter 17, Anodos is accosted by a group of fairies and this is what he narrates

> I attempted to run away, but they all rushed upon me, and laying hold of every part that afforded a grasp, held me tight, crowding around me like bees, they shouted an insect-swarm of exasperating speeches up into my face...
> The Galvanic torrent of this battery of malevolence stung to life within me a spark of nobleness...(p. 213, of the Johannsen edition)

These two episodes of ‘Phantastes’ are obviously related and in each of them a creature is forced violently to release sparks by their fairy captors and tormentors. What is the possible reasons for MacDonald to include both these analogous violent electrical events within *Phantastes*?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that in the second quote the "Galvanic torrent" is metaphorical.

Comment: It's great to see another George MacDonald question!

Answer (score -1):

A young George MacDonald studied science during his university career, at The University of Aberdeen, including the new and exciting scientific developments - and coinage of new terms like Cathode and Anode - related to Electricity, especially those of Michael Faraday (see Hal Broome’s “The Scientific Basis of MacDonald’s Dream Frame” and Soto’s “Mirrors in MacDonald’s *Phantastes*”).

Thus, MacDonald cleverly makes his cat partake of the nature of the cat(ode)

> Cathode, n.

a. The path by which an electric current leaves the electrolyte and passes into the negative pole; the point or surface in contact with the negative pole...
1834   M. Faraday Exper. Res. Electr. (1839) §663   The cathode is that surface at which the current leaves the decomposing body, and is its positive extremity... (OED)

And then MacDonald does the same with Anodos

> Anode, n.
> ...
> a. strictly, as applied by Faraday: The path by which an electric current leaves the positive pole, and enters the electrolyte, on its way to the negative pole. (OED)

Therefore, the fairies seem to be carrying out violent and unwelcome experiments, amounting to torture, with the bio-electric states of both the cat and Anodos.

Comment: This seems a huge stretch; the essay cited makes no connection to electricity or Faraday, and in fact MacDonald seems far more interested in biology and psychology (in modern terms).  The name "Anodos" is customarily interpreted as Greek; the meaning "pathless" fits the protagonist's inability to commit to a course, and it is *extremely* unlikely that a Victorian author would name their character after an obscure pun in a minor scene as opposed to a major character trait.  And, as I've argued above, you've misunderstood that scene anyway.

Comment: MacDonald was interested in science and the new developments in the Electrical Field and that’s why he studies this at Uni.  and why he wrote about it in his books. What you state about naming characters, etc. is probably true, but I never argue for that, far from it.  Another common meaning for the Greek Anodos is “way up,” and that’s why the first “electricians” and MacDonald used it.  The whole “pathless” thing seems to only emerge from people who don’t really understand ‘Phantastes’ and so jump at anything at all that tends to support their biases. The new citation above should help.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but the person you cited has the last name Soto and the first name Fernando. That sounds like they could be you, to be honest. I don't think citing yourself can bolster your answer.

Comment: Why don't you read the paper and then tell me if the answer has been bolstered or not.  I did not at first mention my own work because I thought that people could connect the dots: MacDonald studied science and Electricity at U of Aberdeen, the best known “electrician” in the world at the time was probably MacDonald’s fellow Briton, Michael Faraday, therefore GM came across MF’s work. Because I can point to one usage of Anodos as an Anode does not mean that this is all that GM based his protagonist’s name on, etc.

Comment: Failing to provide a cite (as yourself) is a form of spamming since you've knowingly concealed your presence.